# pnpm install：EACCES：permission denied

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pnpm

env: node 18.16  pnpm 8.6  ubuntu22
code folder: /opt/code/oa-en-collectio

when i use "pnpm install"

```
Packages are hard linked from the content-addressable store to the virtual store.
  Content-addressable store is at: /opt/nodejs/node-v18.16.0-linux-x64/bin/store/v3
  Virtual store is at:             node_modules/.pnpm
 EACCES  EACCES: permission denied, rename '/opt/code/oa-en-collectio/node_modules/.pnpm/registry.npmjs.org+parse-node-version@1.0.1/node_modules/_tmp_19449_35903f3e20930fb491c54e99c6b1e0bf' -> '/opt/code/oa-en-collectio/node_modules/.pnpm/registry.npmjs.org+parse-node-version@1.0.1/node_modules/parse-node-version'.org/antd/4.22.8: 1.49 MB/8.78 MB

pnpm: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/opt/code/oa-en-collectio/node_modules/.pnpm/registry.npmjs.org+parse-node-version@1.0.1/node_modules/_tmp_19449_35903f3e20930fb491c54e99c6b1e0bf' -> '/opt/code/oa-en-collectio/node_modules/.pnpm/registry.npmjs.org+parse-node-version@1.0.1/node_modules/parse-node-version'
```

It is too hard to solve it.....

sudo chmod -R 777 code